# Buttons in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton

I want to create UITableView where some cells are buttons.
Help me, what is the right way to do it?

1) I can use something like that:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
         cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
}

if (indexPath.section == 1){
    if (indexPath.row == 0){


         UIButton* loginButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(9,1,302, 48)];
        [loginButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"LoginButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [loginButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"LoginButton_pressed.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [loginButton setTitle:@"Login" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

        [cell addSubview:loginButton];
        [loginButton release];




    }
}
```

but I see that button is transparent and looks strange.

2) don't use any UIButtons and make what I want entirely using UITableViewCells

Thank you four your attention, I'm completely new for iOS, but I'm trying to make app without xib.

Comment: by default button type would be custom so set the type as buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect

Answer (score 1):

you have not set button type ,it is read only property .so you can not direct assign it so change your code like this:

```
        UIButton* loginButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [loginButton setFrame:CGRectMake(5,5,302, 34)];
        [loginButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"LoginButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [loginButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"LoginButton_pressed.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [loginButton setTitle:@"Login" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [cell addSubview:loginButton];
```